# Convert a gray scal imageto bilevel

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert an image to a binary image (bilevel) using the method "point" of PIL as following:

```
def mappoint (i):
   if i > 1: return 1
   else: return 0

if __name__=="__main__":
   img = Image.open('no.tif')
   img = img.point(mappoint)
   img.save('ok.tif')
```

but it gives me a black image !

EDIT: If I do def `mappoint (i): if i > 1: return 255` then it gives a all white image ! and if I print the value of i in mappoint it shows values from 0 to 255 (like if you do print range(256)), so each i is not the value of each pixels, is it ? There is another way to make the bilevel just by using convert when we open the image: img = `Image.open(img_name).convert('1')` but by default the threshold used is 127, and the doc says to use point method if we want another threshold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function did work, you've generated an image with 0s and 1s. The reason it looks black is because standard images have intensities from 0 to 255.

An intensity of 1 such as you've done looks black because on a scale of 0 to 255, 1 is very close to 0.

Change your `mappoint` to do `if i>1: return 255` if you wanted a black and white image.

Comment: If I do `def mappoint (i): if i > 1: return 255` then it gives a all white image ! and if I print the value of i in mappoint it shows values from 0 to 255 (like if you do print range(256)), so each i is not the value of each pixels, is it ? There is another way to make the bilevel just by using convert when we open the image: `img = Image.open(img_name).convert('1')` but by default the threshold used is 127, and the doc says to use point method if we want another threshold.

Comment: Well, what threshold do you want? Did you **try** the default threshold? What do you find unsatisfactory about that result?

Comment: If you look at your `mappoint` definition...you've set the threshold to be 1. So only black pixels (and very nearly black pixels) will remain black, and the rest will remain white. Chances are the image you're testing this on doesn't have enough black pixels for you to notice.....    Try changing the threshold to 127 to see what I mean.

Comment: Using `def mappoint (i): if i > 127: return 255` still give an all white image, I'm not sure this is how we use the threshold with point method ! @KarlKnechtel I want to use point method because using `img = Image.open(img_name).convert('1')` (which by default use a threshold of 127) don't give a good result: see the [original image](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/326802ae07001norm1.png) and what I get if I use .convert('1') : [resulting image](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/35207529ok.png)

Comment: This is exactly how you should be using `point`. The problem is you have to pick the right threshold for your particular images, which has been hard for us to do as before now we've never had an example of your images! Why don't you examine the intensities of your images to choose an appropriate threshold. For example, try 200.

Comment: Ok it seems to be good for this image with 200, but not for others. How can I choose the threeshold based on the intensities

Comment: Have you ever actually studied how images are stored or represented on a computer? Did you try examining your image with an image editing program to see what the brightness value is for the lines?